# Difference between dispatch_async and peformSelectorInBackground

Tags: ios, objective-c, asynchronous

When I push a `ViewController` with a `MapView` on it i need to draw a route. This takes kinda of 2 seconds so i want to make this in another thread because i don't want to block the UI.

I used:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH,0) ...
```

If i am doing the drawing here, it takes like 10 - 15 seconds.

If i use the `performSelectorInBackground` method the route appears after ~ 1 or 2 seconds.

Why? Shouldn't `PRIORITY_HIGH` be fast?

Comment: What do you draw exactly?

Comment: Kinda of a GPS Logger. I have an array with points and i use `MKPolyline *line = [MKPolyline polylineWithCoordinates:count:]` and then `[self.mapView addOverlay:line]`. The array it's pretty big. :)

Comment: Are you calling `[self.mapView addOverlay:line]` from within the background code block? Because that's almost certainly not safe to do from anything but the main thread.

Comment: Yes, i am doing that in background. I considered this problem, but i still wanted to give it a try just to see how it behaves. But this doesn't explain why performSelectorInBackground is faster, right?

Comment: @VladBogdan: Well, it actually might. You're doing this from the background, which is not safe, and therefore you're essentially invoking undefined behavior. I bet performSelectorInBackground isn't *faster*, it's just that doing it in dispatch_async is simply not actually redrawing immediately. For example, if `-addOverlay:` does something with the current runloop, then that is a noop in the `dispatch_async`, but it will actually do something in the performSelectorInBackground case.

Comment: @VladBogdan: But the point remains that doing this off of the main thread is absolutely not safe, and you shouldn't even be attempting to do so, let alone trying to draw conclusions about various background processing mechanisms based on this.

Comment: Ok. I understand. I will move [self.mapView addOverlay] in the main thread and i will build the route in another thread.

Comment: I think that was the problem. Post it as answer and i will accept it! :) Thanks, man!

Answer (score 0):

You are not supposed to update UI in the background, really anything could happen. Wether you use `dispatch_async` or `performSelectorInBackground:` should take about the same time to process your data. The difference in time you are experiencing is how long the GUI takes to notice that something changed in the background. I can’t explain why this is different between those two methods, this is an undocumented implementation detail.

The correct way to handle this is to call back to the main thread to  update your UI after processing the data in the background. With GCD this could look like this:

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue( 0, 0 );
dispatch_async( queue, ^{
   id result = [self doExpensiveCalculation];
   dispatch_async( dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self updateUIWithResult: result];
   } );
} );
```

Try to implement this pattern once with GCD and once with the `performSelector...` methods and you should notice no difference in time.